# Child position absolute inside parent absolute z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Parent absolute must be under child absolute
How to solve this problem with css?

Positions must be absolute.

```
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">child</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">child</div>
    </div>
```

[My code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ujtjB/)

Comment: I'm using isotope js to place elements.

Comment: But problem is i have elements that out of the parent div on mouseover

Comment: Please try to be a little clearer on what you're trying to accomplish. So far, what I'm seeing, is two `div`s whose children are hidden until they are hovered on and you're saying that "parent absolute must be under child absolute", which I'm having a hard time understanding. What do you mean by "under"?

Comment: First child must be above than second parent on hover.

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev Can you please clarify a little bit more?

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev So, you're wanting the first child to overlap the second parent div? I think Moshen just answered it, if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit this class:

```
.child {
position: absolute;
right: -280px;   /* add this and remove left:0; */
top: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 280px;
height: 300px;
background: #0f0;
display: none;
z-index: 1;   /* add this to set child over the second parent */
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujtjB/2/)

Comment: You didn't solve my problem. Green child must be above both parents

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev He actually did understand you and solved it. Try adding in z-index yourself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ujtjB/3/ @Moshen I think your fiddle is messing up. Here's a better example.

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev: I did what you said buddy "First child must be above than second parent on hover"